# stream fql works only when the limit is 100 - not working for limit 1

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I tried this in developer tool as well as inside an application.

```
SELECT message, description, post_id, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type=46
```

Which is not working

```
SELECT message, description, post_id, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type=46 LIMIT 1
```

which is not working

```
SELECT message, description, post_id, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type=46 LIMIT 100
```

which is working fine for me.

What do i do wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. The problem with querying `stream` with a `LIMIT` of 1, is that the post your query returns may not be visible to you. Facebook filters the results *after* the query completes.

If you want just one post, request more than you need, and filter it down to one on the client side.

See [this SO thread](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14268907/fql-stream-doesnt-return-the-number-of-posts-as-defined-by-limit/14269101#14269101) for more information.

Comment: SELECT message FROM status where uid=me() which returns some data. But SELECT message, description, post_id, likes, comments, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type=46 LIMIT 100 return zero results. why?

Comment: Check `SELECT message,description,post_id,type FROM status WHERE uid=me() LIMIT 100` and see if you have any posts there with `type`=46. Maybe what you think are photos are considered something else by Facebook.

Comment: Yeah tried. I even tried SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time  FROM stream  WHERE source_id = me() AND message = 'status_message' //which i got it from status table

Comment: I recently stopped using fb. I am trying to get my few years old status messages by the way!